# How do i get the value of a obj label

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object

here is the obj :

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#538 (9)
    { 
        ["term_id"]=> string(3) "152" 
        ["name"]=> string(19) "Éducation physique" 
        ["slug"]=> string(18) "education-physique" 
        ["term_group"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> string(3) "159" 
        ["taxonomy"]=> string(11) "product_cat" 
        ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["parent"]=> string(3) "123" 
        ["count"]=> string(1) "3"
    }
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#540 (9)
    {
        ["term_id"]=> string(3) "123" 
        ["name"]=> string(5) "Sport" 
        ["slug"]=> string(5) "sport" 
        ["term_group"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> string(3) "123" 
        ["taxonomy"]=> string(11) "product_cat" 
        ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["parent"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["count"]=> string(2) "49"
    } 
}
mam :
```

i try to get the value : [term_id] of 152. what i need it the "152" value in a variable. i try :     `$product_category->term_id` it return "nothing"
and i try : `$product_category['term_id']` it return "nothing"

How is the "proper" way to retreive value from object

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading you right, and `$product_category` is the entire variable, you have two objects in an array.  So you'll need to tell PHP which array item you're after before trying to access the object.

Something like `$product_category[0]->term_id` should work.

Comment: Boy, i look stupid, when it's all in one line like that it's hard to see.... you are absolutely right... two object, i must select one... my fault !

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution :

Convert this object to an array using `json_decode`, then get the values from array

```
$array   = json_decode($json_string, true);

$term_id = $array[0]['term_id'];
```

OR to get both values :

```
foreach($array as $val){
   echo $val['term_id'];
}
```